# Trying to generate a list of product/vendor ids using PyUSB

Tags: python, pyusb

I am trying to generate a list of product/vendor IDs with Pyusb and I am having trouble. I found a suggestion online from orangecoat.

```
import sys
import usb.core
import usb.util

dev = usb.core.find(find_all=True)

if dev is None:
   raise ValueError('Device not found')

cfg = dev.get_active_configuration()
```

Python gives the following error though:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/usbfinddevices.py", line 10, in <module>
    cfg = dev.get_active_configuration()
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'get_active_configuration'
```

Could someone help me understand why I am getting this error?
Thank you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Save this script

**`test.py`**

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

dev = usb.core.find(find_all=True)

# get next item from the generator
d = dev.next() 
print d.get_active_configuration()
```

then, run this

`sudo python test.py`

On Windows with Python 3 you need to change line `d = dev.next()` to `d = next(dev)` (as pointed out in the comments by @gabin)

Comment: For python3 the following code is valid: 
d = next(dev)
print(d.get_active_configuration())

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, but you need to iterate through your `dev` object which is a generator.

```
dev = usb.core.find(find_all=True)
for d in dev:
    print usb.util.get_string(d,128,d.iManufacturer)
    print usb.util.get_string(d,128,d.iProduct)
    print (d.idProduct,d.idVendor)
```

Comment: Ty for the fast response. I tried your suggestion and it did not print anything. I am starting to thing i installed something incorrectly. when i run dev = usb.core.find(find_all=True) and print dev i get the following response, <generator object device_iter at 0x02CDE5F8>. I tried just inputing            print usb.util.get_string(dev, 128, dev.iManufacturer) and i got the error  AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'iManufacturer' again.

Comment: of course not. you're still using the dev iterator and not its elements. Try  usb.util.get_string(dev[0], 128, dev[0].iManufacturer), but you probably don't want the first element.